# Django:How to prevent non authorize users to access reset url to reset password?

Tags: python, django, django-views

*reset url pattern*

```
url(r'^reset/$',
    auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(
        template_name='password_reset.html',
        email_template_name='password_reset_email.html',
        subject_template_name='password_reset_subject.txt',
)
```

this url is basically if user want to reset his password but i want that only login users can access this page.I know i can prevent non-authorize user to access this url with **@login_required** decorator but i'm using **PasswordResetView** which is written by django and i'm unable to use this decorator on it.
Can anyone tell me how i can added this functionality that only login user can access this page and how i can Modify **PasswordResetView** class-view according to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, but it does not make much sense, since often a user will ask for a password reset, if they are not able to login. So by adding a `login_required` decorator, people that forget their password can no longer reset their password.

Anyway, you can just wrap the result of the `.as_view()` function through the decorator:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

urlpatterns = [
    # …
    url(r'^reset/$',
        login_required(auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(
            template_name='password_reset.html',
            email_template_name='password_reset_email.html',
            subject_template_name='password_reset_subject.txt',
        ))
    ),
    # …
]
```

Comment: thanks.I know this does not make much sense but i'm just doing this for practice.